# Magmi Error when importing through CLI

Tags: import, magmi, permissions, cli

I am new to Magento and Magmi but I succeeded in doing an ok Job with Mangento and Magmi on my local virtual server (Mamp). Now I want to go live but I can’t seem to use Magmi on my production server with Bluehost. When I import my product files, it just said NO FILE. I think it is a problem with permissions but I am not really sure. I tried to give 777 permissions to most of the files (Conf, state, …) but doesn’t seem to work. So I decided to go through CLI as I read it doesn’t need permission settings. But when I tried to import with the command line

php magmi.cli.php -mode=create -CSV:filename=/home3/tunique1/public_html/magmi/var/import/simple.csv

The follow error Log appears in CLI folder :

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(./inc/magmi_defs.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home3/tunique1/public_html/magmi/engines/magmi_productimportengine.php on line 11

PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required './inc/magmi_defs.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear:/home3/tunique1/public_html/magmi/inc:/home3/tunique1/public_html/magmi/integration/inc:/home3/tunique1/public_html/magmi/engines') in /home3/tunique1/public_html/magmi/engines/magmi_productimportengine.php on line 11
```

Could you help me with this problem ?

Comment: It is basically saying a file is missing. Make sure the magmi/inc/magmi_defs.php is present.

Comment: Thank you for your reply !  The file is there so I don't really understand why it cannot find it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. After you said it was missing but in fact it did not. I looked around PHP.ini and realised my previous web designer changed the PHP version of my server... Magmi and the UI is working now.

Answer (score -1):

For the NO FILE problem on Magmi UI. I just realised it was the wrong PHP version on my server... i changed from 5.2 to 5.4 and it was working again.

Thank you,